# How can i request values from Apache rewritten url

Tags: php, apache

Ive been trying to get a request values from an apache rewritten url and its not working. This is the code that sends the value from
"localhost/rewritetest/frog" :

```
<a href = "recieve.php?value=frog">Frog</a>
```

The code that recieves the value at "**localhost/rewritetest/recieve.php?value=frog**" :

```
$value = isset($_REQUEST["value"]) ? $_REQUEST["value"] :  '';
echo $value;
```

The above code works very well but when i rewrite the url from my .htaccess file, to turn "**localhost/rewritetest/recieve.php?value=frog** into **localhost/rewritetest/recieve/frog**" using this code in my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^recieve/([^/]+)/?$ recieve.php?value=$1 [QSA]
```

The page succeesfully redirects but is not retrueving $value. Please Help Me

Comment: _"The above code works very well"_. This cannot be, because there is a double quote missing from the `isset()` line. Should be `$_REQUEST["value"]`.

Comment: @lagbox, that is incorrect. The 'pretty' URL will be rewritten as the original URL, passing the backreference as the argument to the `value` parameter. Which would then be present in `$_REQUEST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: I see you fixed your typo. Can you please tell us that you have not manually copied your code into this question? We need to be sure that what you're showing is in fact _exactly_ the code that you've been testing with.

Comment: I manually typed in the code. Lemme enter in the code I've been testing with

Comment: Try and disable `MultiViews`, that is often the culprit in such situations, where there is such a partial overlap between the “fake” URL, and an actually existing file (here the overlap between `recieve` and `recieve.php`.)

Comment: How do I disable multiviews